# Not-replied emails reminder in OS X Mail v9.3

Tags: macos, automation, apple-mail

After replying to a message, I always move thread to Archive folder with `cmd+shift+A`. However, I need to track, if a recipient didn't reply after N days, I need to remind him: «Hey, did you get my last message? Is everything OK?». Is there any Mail addons, that may provide such feature?

Please, note, only Apple Mail solutions are appreciated. Due to several reasons I can't move to AirMail, MailPilot, etc.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405313/get-the-date-of-an-email-via-applescript) over on Stack Overflow should have enough AppleScript to get you started. You could have this script run in the background, parsing out the sent date of the items in the folder you mention, and give you an alert popup or some other action.

I'm also aware of a commercial product, [MailButler](https://www.feingeist.io/mailbutler/#FollowUp), which explicitly has follow up reminders as you describe them as a "coming soon" feature.

Comment: After 3+ months of using Mailbutler, I definitely confirm it does exactly what it says. In addition, it has a lot a cool features like attachment uploads to cloud services or mail tracking. It worth 9$/mo, for sure. Thanks for brilliant answer!

Answer (score 0):

They will release the follow-up feature for Apple Mail next week (Tuesday). https://www.feingeist.io/mailbutler/

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)